# Run code right after compilation

Tags: elisp, hooks

As I understand, Emacs doesn't really support multi-threading. Because of
this I've chosen to run some operation (it can take a while) with `compile`
function. This is asynchronous and all in all it seemed like a good solution
at first.

Now I need to wait until compilation ends and perform other actions (again
they should not freeze Emacs, so they will be probably new `compile` calls)
once it's finished.

So, it would be good if there were `after-compilation-hook` or something
like that, because `compilation-exit-message-function` doesn't work, as it's
called when compilation is not formally finished.

Is there some way I can perform actions after compilation process (I'm
referring to process created by `compile`)? Please note that I cannot
concatenate all commands into one big command and feed it to `compile` at
once because the commands are not known in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `compilation-finish-functions`:

```
(defun my-compilation-finish-function (buffer desc)
  (message "Buffer %s: %s" buffer desc))
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'my-compilation-finish-function)
```

Comment: This definitely should do the trick. Thanks a lot!