# Dedicated compile hook on compilation finish

Tags: hooks, compilation

I use the `compilation-finish-functions` hook to [perform some actions once compilation finishes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14187/run-code-right-after-compilation).  However, unexpectedly to me the hook is also triggered when `rgrep` completes.

I can't seem to find a more appropriate hook for what I'm after, namely a hook that is triggered **only** when `compile`'s compilation completes.

Is there such a hook or must I take this into consideration in my hooked functions?

This is how I hook my function (Emacs 25.1.1):

```
(defun display-piped-output (buffer msg)
  (unless (string-match "^finished" msg)
    (switch-to-buffer "test.log")))

(define-minor-mode moscow-compilation-mode
  "Expect compilation output piped to file"
  :global t
  (if moscow-compilation-mode
      (add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'display-piped-output)
    (remove-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'display-piped-output)))
```

Comment: Are you sure `rgrep` is doing this?  `compilation-finish-functions` is not mentioned anywhere in `grep.el`.

Comment: @Dan I believe so, but I can certainly dig some more into it!

Comment: Try it without your init file (`emacs -Q`).  If `rgrep` does not trigger `compilation-finish-functions`, bisect your init file recursively until you isolate what's happening.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I can replicate the behavior without init-files; my Emacs version is 25.1.1.

Comment: Following up on sshaw's answer, note that any command which generates a list of results where each one is associated with a given line from a given file (such that you can navigate to the location in question from that buffer) is almost certainly using the `compile` machinery behind the scenes. (And of course, you can do the same thing any time you have a similar use-case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rgrep` and similar use `compile`, this is why hooks in `compilation-finish-functions` are triggered. When `rgrep` successfully completes its message is `"finished\n"`.

You must take this into consideration in your hook by checking `buffer`:

```
(defun display-piped-output (buffer msg)
  (unless (and
           (string-match "^finished" msg))
           (not (string= (buffer-name buffer) "*grep*"))
    (switch-to-buffer "test.log")))
```

Comment: Depending on what you wish to test for specifically, it may also/alternatively be helpful to test the values of `major-mode` (e.g. `grep-mode`) or `compilation-arguments` within the compilation buffer.